# Redux won't update state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux for the first time, and my demo app won't update its default state. I've also tried using useEffect to subscribe to my state, but that still does not log the updated state.

actions.ts

```js
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const setUsername = createAction<string>('auth/setUsername')
export const setPassword = createAction<string>('auth/setPassword')
export const setModalOpen = createAction<boolean>('auth/setModalOpan')
```

hooks.ts

```js
import { useCallback, useMemo } from 'react'
import { setUsername,setPassword,setModalOpen } from './actions'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {IAuth} from './reducer'
import {AppState} from '../index'

export function useSetUsername(): (payload:string)=>void {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return useCallback((payload)=>dispatch(setUsername(payload)), [dispatch])
}

export function useSetPassword(): (payload:string)=>void {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return useCallback((payload)=>dispatch(setPassword(payload)), [dispatch])
}

export function useSetModalOpen(): (payload:boolean)=>void {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return useCallback((payload)=>dispatch(setModalOpen(payload)), [dispatch])
}

export function useGetAuthState():IAuth {
  return useSelector((state:AppState)=>state.payload)
}
```

reducer.ts

```js
import { createReducer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {setUsername, setPassword, setModalOpen} from './actions'

export interface IAuth{
  username: string;
  password: string;
  modalOpen: boolean;
}

const initialState:IAuth = {
  username: '',
  password: '',
  modalOpen: false
}

export default createReducer(initialState, builder=>
  builder
.addCase(setUsername, (state ,action)=>{
  state = {...state, username:action.payload}
})
.addCase(setPassword,(state,action)=>{
  state = {...state, password:action.payload}
})
.addCase(setModalOpen,(state,action)=>{
  state = {...state, modalOpen:action.payload}
})
  )
```

implementation.tsx

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSetPassword, useSetUsername, useSetModalOpen, useGetAuthState} from './state/auth/hooks'

function Review():JSX.Element {
  const match = useRouteMatch()
  const authState = useGetAuthState()
  const setUsername = useSetUsername()
  setUsername('why wont this work?')


  function Topic(){
    let {topicId} = useParams<{topicId:string}>()
    console.log(authState)
    console.log(topicId)
    return <>The topic is... {topicId}</>
  }

  function Main(){
    return (
      <div>
        Primary Page
      </div>
    )
  }

  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`}>
        <Topic/>
      </Route>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/`}>
        <Main />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
}

export default Review;
```

I want to run setUsername() and then log the result output from getAuthState().
When I run this, I just get my default state in the log. I've tried useEffect to subscribe to authState, but that does not change anything for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think also your issue is in your reducers, the issue being that you are reassigning the `state` variable. You should either directly mutate the state draft object ***or*** return a new state object. Note that state reassignment is neither of these.

[Redux Toolkit Direct State Mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#direct-state-mutation)

> Writing "mutating" reducers simplifies the code. It's shorter, there's
> less indirection, and it eliminates common mistakes made while
> spreading nested state. However, the use of Immer does add some
> "magic", and Immer has its own nuances in behavior. You should read
> through pitfalls mentioned in the immer docs . Most importantly, **you
> need to ensure that you either mutate the state argument or return a
> new state, *but not both***.

[pitfalls mentioned in the immer docs - Don't reassign the recipe argument](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/pitfalls/#dont-reassign-the-recipe-argument)

> Never reassign the draft argument (example: `draft = myCoolNewState`).
> Instead, either modify the `draft` or return a new state.

So you should either mutate the draft state:

```
export default createReducer(initialState, builder =>
  builder
    .addCase(setUsername, (state, action) => {
      state.username = action.payload;
    })
    .addCase(setPassword,(state, action) => {
      state.password = action.payload;
    })
    .addCase(setModalOpen,(state, action) => {
      state.modalOpen = action.payload;
    })
);
```

Or return new state objects:

```
export default createReducer(initialState, builder =>
  builder
    .addCase(setUsername, (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      username: action.payload,
    }))
    .addCase(setPassword,(state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      password: action.payload,
    }))
    .addCase(setModalOpen,(state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      modalOpen: action.payload,
    }))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You would need to return a state in each `addCase`**

So change your reducer to:

```
export const store = createReducer(initialState, (builder) =>
  builder
    .addCase(setUsername, (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      username: action.payload,
    }))
    .addCase(setPassword, (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      password: action.payload,
    }))
    .addCase(setModalOpen, (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      modalOpen: action.payload,
    }))
);
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit amazing-cohen-4imhi]

Comment: `state.username = action.payload`